# If $\mathcal S$ is a subbase for a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X,$ then show that $\mathcal S\setminus \{\phi,X\}$ is also a subbase for $\mathcal T.$

Tags: general-topology

**My attempt:** Let $U$ be a $\mathcal T$-open set. Then by hypothesis, for $S_{i_k}\in\mathcal S$, we can write: $$U=\cup_i(S_{i_{1}}\cap S_{i_{2}}\cap\cdots\cap S_{i_{n_i}}).\tag1$$ Now without loss of generality, we can choose $S_{i_1}$ to be $\phi.$ Then from $(1),$ we see that $U=\phi\in\mathcal T.$ Similarly, letting $S_{i_1}$ to be $X$ yields: $$U=\cup_i (\cap_{k=2}^{n_i}S_{i_k})\in\mathcal T.$$ So, according to me, presence or absence of $X$ and $\phi$ in $\mathcal S$ does not matter for $\mathcal S$ to be a subbase for the topology $\mathcal T$ on $X.$ Hence the result follows.

But, I don't think this argument would qualify as a formal argument for the same. So please suggest me one. And if I have done any mistake please point out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any collection $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ let us denote the topology that is generated by $\mathcal U$ as $\tau(\mathcal U)$.

Then it is straightforward on base of the definition of $\tau(\mathcal U_1)$ that: $$\tau(\mathcal U_1)\subseteq\tau(\mathcal U_2)\iff\mathcal U_1\subseteq\tau(\mathcal U_2)$$

So  proving that $\tau(\mathcal U_1)=\tau(\mathcal U_2)$ boils down to proving that: $$\mathcal U_1\subseteq\tau(\mathcal U_2)\text{ and }\mathcal U_2\subseteq\tau(\mathcal U_1)$$
Application of this on $\mathcal U_1=\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal U_2=\mathcal S-\{\varnothing,X\}$ is fruitful.

Especially because the sets $\varnothing$ and $X$ are elements of every topology on $X$.

We find that: $$\tau(\mathcal S-\{\varnothing,X\})=\tau(\mathcal S)=\mathcal T$$or equivalently that $\mathcal S-\{\varnothing,X\}$ is a subbase for $\mathcal T$.